# Remove jsonb array element by value

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I did figure out how to remove a value from an array for a single record, but how to do it for many of them. The problem is in the way how I use the subquery. As it has to return only single element. Maybe my approach is wrong.

```
    Given input: '{attributes:['is_new', 'is_old']}'
    Expected result '{attributes: ['is_old']}' #remove 'is_new' from jsonb array
```

```
    Real example:
    #   sku  |           properties 
    # -------+--------------------------------
    #  nu3_1 | {                             +
    #        |     "name": "silly_hodgkin",  +
    #        |     "type": "food",           +
    #        |     "attributes": [           +
    #        |         "is_gluten_free",     +
    #        |         "is_lactose_free",    +
    #        |         "is_new"              +
    #        |     ]                         +
    #        | }
```

```
#Query that removes single array element:

SELECT c.sku, jsonb_agg(el) FROM
catalog c JOIN (select sku, jsonb_array_elements_text(properties->'attributes') as el from catalog) c2 ON c.sku=c2.sku where el  'is_new'
GROUP BY c.sku;
```

```
#Update query that removes single array element in single record

UPDATE catalog SET properties=jsonb_set(properties, '{attributes}', (
    SELECT jsonb_agg(el) FROM
    catalog c JOIN (select sku, jsonb_array_elements_text(properties->'attributes') as el from catalog) c2 ON c.sku=c2.sku
    WHERE el  'is_new' AND c.sku='nu3_1'
    GROUP BY c.sku
    )
) WHERE sku='nu3_1';
```

The question again is. How to remove jsonb array element by value for many database records?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_set()` and the delete operator `-`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html):

```
update catalog
set properties = 
    jsonb_set(properties, '{attributes}', (properties->'attributes') - 'is_new');
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=055cb7960f565b98abdc472c36cc93df)

Comment: I did try the '-' operator, before asking the question here but it did not work. What makes it work are the parentheses (properties->'attributes'). Without them it does not work. I do not get it. What is the difference?

I get it now both '->' and '-' are operators. It looks like, that '-' has a higher priority and it tries to use it against two strings, which can not work.
Thank You @klin.

Comment: Is it possible to do a where in this? Say you had objects within an array that had an ID and do where ID = 1?

Comment: @NickPocock - yes, you can add where clause like in any other `UPDATE` statement, see [this example.](http://rextester.com/SOAVV7330)

Comment: How about for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299061/removing-element-from-array-within-object-jsonb

Struggling massively!

Comment: This was failing for me, but only because I was using a JSON text as the second argument (like `- '"new"'` instead of `- 'new'`) and Postgres was interpreting it as a normal text value with quotes. Just use a normal text without quotes and it will work.

Comment: Hi, @klin, If I have a field `parents` with content  `[123, 345, 789]`, can I remove an element say `123` with jsonb_set, or if there is any other solutions ?

Comment: @Brook - you cannot directly use the solution in the answer for a numeric json array. I think that the simplest way in this case is a custom function but there maybe alternative solutions. Please, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

So, I believe QRY you are looking for is:

```
with q as (
  select distinct sku, jsonb_set(properties,'{attributes}',jsonb_agg(el) over (partition by sku),false) new_properties
  from (
    select 
      sku, jsonb_array_elements_text(properties->'attributes') as el, properties
    from catalog
  ) p
  where el != 'is_new'
)
update catalog set properties = q.new_properties from q where catalog.sku = q.sku
;
```

be aware that I assumed your `sku` is at least `UK`!

Comment: I just rewrote the question qry so it would work .I would definetely prefer `-` operator myself

Answer (score 1):

Your solution works + you pointed me to some new stuff like window functions and give me an idea for alternative solution:

```sql
WITH q as (
  SELECT c.sku as sku,  jsonb_set(properties, '{attributes}', jsonb_agg(el)) as new_properties
    FROM catalog c JOIN (select sku, jsonb_array_elements_text(properties->'attributes') as el from catalog) c2 ON c.sku=c2.sku where el != 'is_new'
    GROUP BY c.sku
)
UPDATE catalog SET properties=q.new_properties FROM q WHERE catalog.sku=q.sku;
```

Answer (score 0):

as per [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

> json_build_object ( VARIADIC "any" ) → json
>
> jsonb_build_object ( VARIADIC "any" ) → jsonb
>
> Builds a JSON object out of a variadic argument list. By convention,
> the argument list consists of alternating keys and values. Key
> arguments are coerced to text; value arguments are converted as per
> to_json or to_jsonb.
>
> json_build_object('foo', 1, 2, row(3,'bar')) → {"foo" : 1, "2" :
> {"f1":3,"f2":"bar"}}

```
update catalog
set properties = properties - 'attributes' || jsonb_build_object('attributes','[is_gluten_free,is_lactose_free,is_new]')
where properties ? 'attributes' 
returning *;
```

Now you can replace the key, also replace value. Just Make sure the `attributes` as top-level key.