# Removing element from array within object JSONB

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am attempting to remove an element from my database. The element I want to remove is within a JSON object called playerContainer which contains an array named players. This all sits within a table called site_content. I am trying to remove the object based on it's ID, however I get this error.

> DELETE elem
>                       from site_content,
>                       lateral jsonb_array_elements(content->'playersContainer'->'players') elem
>                       where elem @> '{"id":"22"}'
>              because: ERROR: syntax error at or near "elem"   Position: 27

Below is my query, can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
DELETE elem 
from site_content, 
lateral jsonb_array_elements(content->'playersContainer'->'players') elem 
where elem @> '{"id":"1"}'
```

Here is the sample JSON

```
"playersContainer": {
        "players": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Nick",
                "teamName": "Shire Soldiers",
                "ratings": [
                    1,
                    5,
                    6,
                    9
                ],
                "assists": 17,
                "manOfTheMatches": 20,
                "cleanSheets": 1,
                "data": [
                    3,
                    2,
                    3,
                    5,
                    6
                ],
                "totalGoals": 19

            },
}
```

Comment: Provide your JSON data example

Comment: I have posted some sample JSON above.

Comment: Please, provide the table definition (`\d site_content` in psql).

Comment: "footballprototype";"public";"site_content";"id";1;"";"NO";"character varying";255;1020;;;
"footballprototype";"public";"site_content";"content";2;"";"YES";"jsonb";;;;;

Comment: I have one table called site_content, with 2 rows, one called id and one called content which has the JSON in above

Answer (score 4):

[DELETE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-delete.html) works on rows of a table. Therefore you can't use it unless if you want to remove the complete row.

Try this:

```
create temp table testing as
select 
    '{ "playersContainer": {
        "players": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Nick"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Rick"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Trick"
            }
        ]
     }}'::jsonb as value;
```

Now you need to find the position of the player you want to remove, lets say you want Rick with id 2 (minus 1 because index starts from 0)

```
select position-1 from testing, jsonb_array_elements(value->'playersContainer'->'players') with ordinality arr(elem, position) WHERE elem->>'id' = '2';
```

Now you can combine this with an `UPDATE` statement to update the field. Use minus (-) operator to remove the element at wanted index.

```
UPDATE testing SET value = jsonb_set(value, '{playersContainer,players}', (value->'playersContainer'->'players') - (select position-1 from testing, jsonb_array_elements(value->'playersContainer'->'players') with ordinality arr(elem, position) WHERE elem->>'id' = '2')::int );
```

End result:

```
{
    "playersContainer":{
        "players":[
            {
                "id":"1",
                "name":"Nick"
            },
            {
                "id":"3",
                "name":"Trick"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This fails for me if the element is not found (it will remove all the elements in the "players")... any ideas?

Comment: Divide it into 2 queries. execute UPDATE only if position was found in the previous query?

Comment: — yes, this is what I ended up doing